# how to extract parametres used by PCA in a first dataset and apply them to another one using Python

Tags: python, pca, coefficients

I'm trying to verify if the transformation done by PCA is the same for 2 datasets, so I applied PCA for the training dataset and I want to extract parameters in order to apply them to a test dataset given that we are in unsupervised case (no labels)

Comment: If you want some help, show some code...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sklearn.decomposition.PCA.transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.transform). This works just like any other fit-transform procedure in scikit-learn.